# Hive: How do we mask a particular key value pair ( containing PII data) in a json object, residing in a column, in Hive?

Tags: sql, json, security, hive, masking

There is PII data that exists inside a key-value pair of a json object stored inside my Hive table in a column.Is there any way that I can mask only the value of the required key-value pair while keeping others unmasked?

```
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null, "mob_no": "99999999"}
```

I require field `"mob_no"` which is PII data and its associated value to be masked. Other key-value pairs of the json should be visible

Comment: Please provide data example

Comment: { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null, "mob_no": "99999999"}

I require field ("mob_no") which is PII data and its associated value to be masked. Other key-value pairs of the json should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` to replace some values in json with some string (see `json_with_number_replaced` column in the example below).

Better apply `sha256` instead of simple replacement, because this function is cryptographically strong (not reversible one way function), deterministic and collision tolerant. These properties of [sha256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hash function allow you to join on obfuscated values(if using the same obfuscation method) and do aggregations. You can still count different mobile_numbers after obfuscation.  See `mobile_number_obfuscated` and `json_with_number_obfuscated` columns calculation in the example below:

```
select json original_json,
       s.original_mobile_number,
       s.mobile_number_obfuscated,
       regexp_replace(s.json, '(mob_no":[\\s]?")([+]?[\\d]+)','$1xx') as json_with_number_replaced,
       regexp_replace(s.json, '(mob_no":[\\s]?")([+]?[\\d]+)',concat('$1',mobile_number_obfuscated)) as json_with_number_obfuscated
from
(
select regexp_extract(s.json, 'mob_no":[\\s]?"([+]?[\\d]+)',1) as original_mobile_number,
       java_method('org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils', 'sha256Hex', regexp_extract(s.json, 'mob_no":[\\s]?"([+]?[\\d]+)',1)) mobile_number_obfuscated,
       s.json
from
(--original data
select '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null, "mob_no": "+99999999"}' as json
)s
)s;

OK
original_json                                                   original_mobile_number  mobile_number_obfuscated                                                json_with_number_replaced                               json_with_number_obfuscated
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null, "mob_no": "+99999999"}   +99999999               98ae38dddc1994179e21d104feb7b09e5627953d9fe9b9851239ac445b6de3cd        { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null, "mob_no": "xx"}  { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null, "mob_no": "98ae38dddc1994179e21d104feb7b09e5627953d9fe9b9851239ac445b6de3cd"}
Time taken: 1.988 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

In this example I demonstrated how you can use regexp_replace to replace value for some key in the JSON, also how to use sha256 to obfuscate your PII data.