# Masking a Substring in Hive Views

Tags: sql, json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to create a View on top of a Hive Table, masking data in a particular column.
The Table has a column of String Type. The data in that particular column is of JSON structure. I need to mask a value of a particular field say 'ip_address'

```json
{"id":1,"first_name":"john","last_name":"doe","email":"sample@123.com","ip_address":"111.111.111.111"}
```

**expected:**

```json
{"id":1,"first_name":"john","last_name":"doe","email":"sample@123.com","ip_address":null}
```

These are the few [Built-in Hive Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf#LanguageManualUDF-DataMaskingFunctions) I have tried, they don't seem to help my cause.

- mask
- get_json_object
- STR_TO_MAP
- if clause

Also I don't think substring and regexp_Extract are useful here coz the position of the field value is not always predetermined plus I'm not familiar with regex expressions.

PS: Any help is appreciated that would help me avoid writing a new UDF.

Comment: Kindly note the above json is inside a String Type column in Hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regexp_replace:

`select regexp_replace(column_name,'"ip_address":".*?"', '"ip_address":null') as column_name` will work fine with any position.

You can add any number of optional spaces before and after `:`:

`regexp_replace(column_name,'"ip_address" *: *".*?"', '"ip_address":null')`

Regexp `'"ip_address" *: *".*?"'` meaning:

`"ip_address"` - literally "ip_address"

`*` - 0 or more spaces (allowed in json)

`:`  - literally `:`

`*` - 0 or more spaces

`".*?"` - any number of any characters (non-greedy) inside double-quotes.

See also similar question if you want to replace value with some calculated value, for example obfuscate using sha256, not with just null: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54179543/2700344